# Devart.Data.MySql: Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records

Tags: mysql, .net, database

I use C# and Devart.Data.MySql to update rows in database table. But I've got exception

> Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1
>   records

while trying to update row with the same values. For instance I have table data with two columns **Id (primary key) and Title**. I have one row in this table **Id = 222, Title = 4444**. Then I'm trying to update this row with the same values:

```
using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(Cs))
{
    conn.Open();

    //update command
    var uc = new MySqlCommand(@"UPDATE data SET Title = @Title WHERE Id = @Id", conn);
    uc.Parameters.Add("@Title", MySqlType.VarChar, 50, "Title");
    uc.Parameters.Add("@Id", MySqlType.VarChar, 50, "Id");

    //create adapter
    var adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("", conn)
    {
        UpdateBatchSize = 100,
        UpdateCommand = uc
    };
    adapter.TableMappings.Add("Table", "data");

    //create table
    var table = new DataTable("data");
    DataColumn col = table.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(string));
    col.Unique = true;
    table.PrimaryKey = new[] { col };
    table.Columns.Add("Title", typeof(string));

    //create dataset
    var ds = new DataSet();
    ds.Tables.Add(table);

    DataRow row = table.NewRow();
    row["Id"] = "222";
    row["Title"] = "4444";
    table.Rows.Add(row);
    row.AcceptChanges();
    row.SetModified();

    adapter.Update(ds);
}
```

After that I've got exception here about concurrency violation. If I use for Title another value it works fine. It Looks like without some timestamp or modified value I can't execute update command with the same values. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this behavior is by design and can be changed by providing the following option is your connection string:

```
Found Rows=true;
```

This option was introduced in version 7.0.25, as it is noted [here](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/revision_history.html).